# Maven with Findbugs

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, findbugs, m2e

I am running findbugs and maven with this plugin and then the build fails even though if I run find bugs with the max setting of 20 through Eclipse I get 0 bugs. Now it fails with 33.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <threshold>Ignore</threshold>
      <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>verify</phase> 
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal> 
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Two questions:

Why is there such a discrepancy between the Eclipse Findbugs plugin and the Maven Findbugs plugin?

Can I somehow make Eclipse Findbugs load the findbugscheck.xml generated from Maven Findbugs, so that my code is automatically highlighted. Fishing through the xml file is very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discrepancy between the Eclipse Findbugs plugin and findbugs-maven-plugin is likely due to these two offerings using different versions of the Findbugs utility. Each of these offerings is running the FindBugs utility ([found here](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net)) and then parsing the output of the utility and displaying the results. The findbugs-maven-plugin-2.0.1 is based on Findbugs 1.3.8. I cannot say what version of Findbugs your Eclipse plugin is based upon.

The Findbugs utility supports some [command line options](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html#d0e511) (such as -effort:max, -effort:min) that can effect the results. The Eclipse Findbugs plugin and findbugs-maven-plugin may be supplying different command line options resulting in a disparity in results. It might be possible to eliminate this disparity by if they both offer configuration for these command line options.

The Eclipse Findbugs plugin offers some filtering of the results in the plugin's view inside of Eclipse. The filtering is accessible in the plugin's view as a tool bar icon (not 100% sure of the location of this as I am not on my dev box at the moment).

Also, from the Findbugs [website](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/factSheet.html):

> "FindBugs supports a plugin architecture allowing anyone to add new bug detectors."

This could mean that the Eclipse plugin has has plugged in other bug detectors, but I do not know this to be the case, it is just a possibility to be pointed out. I have never found a way to get the Eclipe Findbugs plugin load the findbugscheck.xml from the maven build.

ETA: Instead of fishing through the findbugs results xml by hand you could try running the [Findbugs GUI](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/gui.html#d0e1149) and using it to load and view the results.